# Can Higman's embedding theorem be generalised that way?

Tags: group-theory, computability, universal-algebra, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose $\mathfrak{U}$ is a variety of groups. Lets define $F_n(\mathfrak{U})$ as [relatively free groups in $\mathfrak{U}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_object)

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated group. We call $G$ finitely presented in $\mathfrak{U}$ iff $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ and finite $A \subset F_n(\mathfrak{U})$ such that $G \cong \frac{F_n(\mathfrak{U})}{\langle \langle A  \rangle \rangle}$. We call $G$ recursively presented in $\mathfrak{U}$ iff $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ and [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_set) $A \subset F_n(\mathfrak{U})$ such that $G \cong \frac{F_n(\mathfrak{U})}{\langle \langle A  \rangle \rangle}$.

My question is:

> Is it true, that a finitely generated group is recursively presented in $\mathfrak{U}$ iff it is isomorphic to a finitely generated subgroup of a group finitely presented in $\mathfrak{U}$?

This fact is true for the varieties of abelian groups due to linear algebra, [proved for the variety of all groups by Higman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_embedding_theorem) and for the Burnside varieties by Olshanski.

However, I do not know, whether it is true in general.

Comment: Do you know how many varieties of groups there are? It seems that in the 1960s they knew that the number was either $\aleph_0$ or $\aleph_1$. If there are uncountably many varieties then this answers your question, as there are then varieties whose free object will not be recursively presentable.

Comment: (Also, this question seems more MathOverflow-ey than Math.Stackexchange-ey.)

Comment: @user1729, yes, there are uncountably many of varieties of groups (it was proved by Olshanski in 1989). However, it seems that I made a typo, when I formulated the question. Actually I wanted to say "finitely presented in $\mathfrak{U}$" and not simply "finitely presented". Thank you, for posting this as a comment and not an answer, thus allowing me to fix my question.

Comment: @user1729 do you mean $\aleph_0$ or $2^{\aleph_0}$? It seems the answer is the latter - and an answer of $\aleph_1$ (without using GCH) would be very surprising to me!

Comment: @Alex I meant $2^{\aleph_0}$. Unsure why I wrote $\aleph_1$ (and the paper I found the problem in also wrote $\aleph_1$).

Comment: *Typo above: "the paper I found the problem in also wrote $2^{\aleph_0}$".